# How to simulate GPU hardware failure?

Tags: kernel, nvidia, gpu

I'm doing some research that has to do with GPGPU resilience with NVIDIA graphics cards and I've been looking for a way to, as accurately as possible, simulate hardware failure. I know about cudaDeviceReset() and using intentionally failing asserts() within the kernel; correct me if I'm wrong but I don't think these accurately portray realistic hardware failure.

Ultimately what I'm trying to achieve is effectively turning off the device during execution, have the host detect this and try to recover from it.

What I'd like to know is if there is some method of "power cycling" the GPU via the Linux kernel.

I'm using CentOS 7 and my device's compute capability is 2.1. Kindly see below for output from uname -a.

```
Linux heisenbug 3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Feb 16 17:03:50 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manipulate some of the pci bus registers of the device fairly easily with **setpci**. Note: this is dangerous and may crash your system!

For example, find the pci bus and slot for your graphics board:

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)

$ lspci -s 00:02.0 -v
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
        Subsystem: Holco Enterprise Co, Ltd/Shuttle Computer Device 4018
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
        Memory at f7400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
        Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
        Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915
```

You can read and write registers using `setpci`. You need to be root to read some registers, and to write any of them. The register names are listed with `setpci --dumpregs`. Eg:

```
$ setpci -s 00:02.0 command   
0407
```

The 16bit pci config `command` register is an important register. The bit meaning can be got from the [linux header](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/linux/pci_regs.h#L32). The low 3 bits are 1 to enable the device to respond to io and memory cycles from the cpu, and to be bus master so that it can dma into the cpu's main memory.

If you disable these bits, the device will no longer respond to your driver.
Beware, **this may crash your system**. Do not test this lightly:

```
$ sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 command=0000 # DONT DO THIS!
```

You can try writing a script to set the register to 0, waiting a few seconds while your graphics tries to draw, then setting the register back to its original setting (command=0407).  All numbers are in hex (without any 0x prefix). As mentioned in the comments, you may need to provide 4 digits for the value, despite the fact that the width of named registers (like `command`) are known by `setpci`.  You can provide an explicit width with a suffix to the register name of `.b` (8bits), `.w` (16), or `.l` (32).

Resetting the hardware is more difficult as it often requires you either to know of a particular register in the hardware to reset, or in the parent bus hardware.

Comment: When I execute `setpci -s 01:00.0 command=0` nothing happens. More specifically, I'm experimenting with a long running CUDA application (matrix multiplication) with no graphical display. Executing that command does not seem to have any effect as the computation continues and finishes without error. Am I missing anything? Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I just got it to work by using `setpci -s 01:00.0 command=0000` instead of `setpci -s 01:00.0 command=0`. And I was able to successfully restart by setting the device back to the initial value. So thanks! I'll mark this as correct but please make the correction in the answer for anyone else who may be looking into doing this.

Comment: That's unexpected. `setpci` knows that the width of the command register is 2 bytes, so setting it to 0 rather than 0000 should suffice. You can also explicitly give the size as a suffix `command.w=0`. Nevertheless, I'll add your info to the answer. Thanks.